# Can't stop song because it has to end before other lines run

Tags: java, jlayer

I just want it to be able to stop halfway through playing the song but not sure how I need to do this?  Does it need to be threaded?

```
public class playMusic {
   public static void main(String[] args){
      try{
          FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("*filePath*");
          Player player = new Player(fileInputStream);
          player.play();
          player.close();
      }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }catch(JavaLayerException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: are you using this http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/docs/docs1.0/javazoom/jl/player/Player.html ?

Comment: yes I'm using that one

Comment: Based on its methods, I think you won't be able to do it. at least you know what you want to stop on some time exact. it'd be while (!player.isComplete()) { if (player.getPosition() == 15000) player.close(); break;}

Comment: But you could use other library that is more complete like https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html if you take a look , you will find methods like getCurrentTime() and getDurantion() so you can divide /2 and find the halfway

Comment: okay thank you.  But when I've got the song running, no other lines run so how do I keep other lines running at the same time? Sorry if it's a really obvious question but only have fairly basic knowledge

Comment: As I told you you can make while (!player.isComplete()) so you can do some code here and break, if you want to implement some thing more advanced so you need to work with threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the program to run two separate threads concurrently have a look at Concurrency/Threads.
Example:

```
class PlayerThread extends Thread {
    private final Player player;

    PlayerThread(Player player) {
        this.player = player;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            player.play();
        } catch (JavaLayerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        String filename = "*filename*";
        try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filename)) {
            // load the file
            Player player = new Player(fileInputStream);
            // start playing music in separate thread
            new PlayerThread(player).start();

            // wait until you want to stop the music,
            // or do something else, maybe wait for user's decision
            Thread.sleep(10_000); // 10 seconds
            // close the player
            player.close();
        } catch (JavaLayerException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

this way one thread runs plays the music while you can interact with the other and give commands. Bear in mind, concurrency is a large and complex topic, if you never used it you may run into some troubles. Study the tutorial:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html